# Wordpress: Turn PHP snippet in to shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, shortcode

I'm trying to turn the following PHP code in to a shortcode called [titles] :

```
<?php echo $_POST['titles']; ?>
```

I have tried adding the following to my functions.php but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
//Add Shortcode
function custom_titles() {
  echo $_POST['titles']; 
}
add_shortcode('titles','custom_titles');
```

Comment: Do you want to simply print `$_POST['title']`? Where you can get `$_POST['title']`?

Comment: Hi, I want to set a form input value as <?php echo $_POST['titles']; ?> so that a value from an input from the previous page is retrieved. The input looks like this: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['titles']; ?>" /> but because PHP isn't executed in my text editor instead I want to turn the PHP snippet in to a shortcode, making the input look like this: <input type="text" value="[titles]" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
function title_func( $atts ){
    $title = '';
    if(isset($_POST['titles'])){
        $title = esc_attr($_POST['titles']);
    }
    return $title;
}
add_shortcode( 'title', 'title_func' );
```

Make sure you have `$_POST['titles']` otherwise it is not going to print anything.